# ios Alljoyn Framework always return a same error

Tags: ios, alljoyn

In IOS i have use Alljoyn Framework for chat on same wifi network . 
so i have simply download v15.04 core SDK but this is not working then i have Try v14.06 with same instruction but this is also return me same error what should i do where i found my solution please help me This is the error

```
d: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

same error in both SDK please share your valuable knowledge 
Thankyou 
I have lots of Try but i can't able to solve this problem 
Here i attach a link where should i do 
[Here is tutorial for version 14 and 15](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/download)

Comment: Did you checked is there any missing framework which is used by Alljoyn Framework..

Comment: Not missing any framework , I have download sdk 15 and go to sample app in ios and run on xcode its not working

Comment: Did you follow these steps.. 
https://allseenalliance.org/developers/develop/building/ios-osx#install-samples-on-an-ios-device

Comment: Yes i follow this steps , i try to one more time